# How to fix "chmod" permissions after running "chmod 222 /bin/chmod"?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, chmod, gnu

I ran `chmod 222 /bin/chmod` to know more about `chmod`. After that, when I run `/bin/chmod`, I get `permission denied`.

I tried to change the permissions of `chmod` back to `755`, but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have tips about how to fix this?

Comment: What I find most fascinating is the ingenuity of the answers here. So far there are 8 different ways to restore 755 permissions to `chmod`.

Comment: @U.Windl: It's one finger misposition off chmod 111, which is sane.

Comment: @ArturMeinild and that's why blacklisting specific commands while allowing general command execution is never a good strategy.

Answer (score 47):

You made `chmod` not executable.

There are three (no, actually four) options to revert from this situation:

1. Reinstall the `coreutils` package, as mentioned in [Artur Meinild's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1483233/618353).
2. My preferred solution:

   - boot from an installation medium and start a live Ubuntu session.
   - start the Disks application, find the partition where your Ubuntu installation resides and mount it. Note the path where the partition is mounted (something like `/media/username/somename`).
   - open a terminal and run:

     ```
     sudo chmod 755 /media/username/somename/usr/bin/chmod
     ```
   - unmount the partition, shutdown the live session and reboot from your normal installation.
3. Be VERY CAREFUL when doing this! Run the following commands:

   ```
   sudo cp -p /usr/bin/ls /tmp/chmod
   sudo cp /usr/bin/chmod /tmp/chmod
   sudo /tmp/chmod 755 /usr/bin/chmod
   ```

   Explanation: first, we copy another file that is still executable (I chose `/usr/bin/ls`) to `/tmp/chmod`. By using the `-p` parameter to the `cp` command, we are preserving permissions, so we ensure that the resulting file is also executable.

   Next, we overwrite the just created `/tmp/chmod` file with the contents of actual `/usr/bin/chmod`, but **without** preserving permissions. The contents of `/tmp/chmod` is overwritten with actual `chmod`, but it is still executable.

   So we can use `/tmp/chmod` to restore permissions on the actual `/usr/bin/chmod`.

   Optionally we can delete `/tmp/chmod`, which is no more needed, but it is not necessary; on the next system boot, `/tmp` directory will be cleared anyway.
4. You can use any programming language that supports the `chmod()` system call. As Ubuntu by default contains the Python interpreter, it would be probably easiest to use Python:

   ```
   sudo python3 -c 'import os; os.chmod("/usr/bin/chmod", 0755)'
   ```

Comment: Option 4 is very simple, and there are several languages that are likely to be available: python, perl, php.

Comment: +1. I had to discover option 3 for myself back in the 90s on a SCO Unix system after I'd (accidentally) removed execute permission from everything in `/bin` by mistake. The emergency boot disk had executable binaries on it, but _not_ a copy of `chmod`!

Comment: +1 for mentioning my favorite clever solution: using `cp` to just copy a different binary with appropriate permissions and overwrite it

Comment: Why is 2 your preferred solution? The others seem easier.

Comment: @AugustJanse : 2 is way more flexible and powerfull: could help restore many things from a sane distro (permissions, suid, owners, etc, using that distro as a reference)

Comment: @AugustJanse I just think it's a "proper" or "canonical" (nothing related to a company name ;)) way to fix such an issue. The first is an overkill, the two others are a bit "hackish". And as mentioned in the comment above, this method is generally used to fix many other broken things.

Comment: Isn’t `/tmp` mounted noexec in Ubuntu?

Comment: @user3840170 `/tmp` usually isn't a separate filesystem at all. It's just a regular directory under the root filesystem, at least in default install.

Answer (score 28):

#### With `dpkg-statoverride`

[`dpkg-statoverride`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/dpkg-statoverride.8.html) is available by default on Ubuntu ... Its main purpose is to override ownership and mode of files ... and you can use it like this:

```
sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 755 /bin/chmod
```

#### With `rsync`

[`rsync`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/rsync.1.html) is available by default on Ubuntu ... In `--archive, -a` mode, it should only set the permissions (*since the file will never change*) ... i.e. when used in one shot like so:

```
sudo rsync -a --chmod=755 /bin/chmod /bin/chmod
```

#### With the `install` command

There is another utility called [`install`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/install.1.html) from [GNU core utilities](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/jammy/+package/coreutils) as well which should be available by default on your system … It’s mainly used for copying just compiled files and make them executable i.e. install them and hence the name … It should give the copied file the permissions of `rwxr-xr-x` by default ... It also has the option `-m` to alter permissions of that file selectively on-the-fly (*while you might not need that option in this case as the defaults should suffice*), but you can always do:

```
sudo install -m +x /bin/chmod mychmod
```

Then, you can simply do:

```
sudo ./mychmod 755 /bin/chmod
```

#### With the dynamic linker/loader

Another simple solution as well is to use the [dynamic linker/loader](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/ld-linux.so.8.html) itself ... This is a special way of running binaries as it doesn’t require permissions to do so (*It is somewhat similar to running a non-executable shell script by passing it as an argument to `/bin/sh` for example*) … Depending on the architecture your binary was compiled for, you most likely want to use the `amd64` variant ... Find its name and path on your system with for example:

```
$ dpkg -S 'ld-linux*'
manpages: /usr/share/man/man8/ld-linux.8.gz
manpages: /usr/share/man/man8/ld-linux.so.8.gz
libc6:amd64: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libc6:i386: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
libc6-i386: /lib32/ld-linux.so.2
libc6:i386: /lib/ld-linux.so.2
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Then, simply use it in one shot like so:

```
sudo /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/chmod 755 /bin/chmod
```

#### Else ...

Search your system for other utilities that can change/set file permissions ... One way is to search the manuals with e.g. `man -K "chmod"` ... Here are some of what I found on my system:

[`chacl`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/chacl.1.html)(*change the access control list of a file or directory*):

```
sudo chacl u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-x /bin/chmod
```

[`bwrap`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/bwrap.1.html)(*container setup utility*):

```
sudo bwrap --die-with-parent --bind / / --chmod 755 /bin/chmod -- /bin/true
```

Comment: Re: dynamic loader: On Debian, and I assume Ubuntu as well, `/usr/bin/ld.so` does the same thing, so the slightly simpler `ld.so /bin/chmod 755 /bin/chmod` would suffice!

Comment: AFAIK using the dynamic loader requires that `/bin/chmod` still has *read* permission I think? So that method would work for mode `6xx` or `4xx` but not `2xx`

Comment: @steeldriver, and Raffa, it still needs to, yes (`cp /bin/ls ./ls; chmod 0 ./ls; /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./ls` and I get an error). But if you're running it as root, you get to ignore such pesky details as the permission bits, as root usually does, so it works there. Nothing to do with the dynamic loader being special here. (That's not to say it wouldn't be special when the kernel loads it as part of the normal process of executing a binary file, but that's what we're doing here.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Ah I see what you mean, ... It should be invoked as the super user with `sudo` as in the example in my answer.

Comment: yes exactly, sudo makes the execution work here. (and of course that should be "that's _not_ what we're doing here." at the end of my last comment, blah.)

Comment: @ilkkachu and @steeldriver ... In the sense of reading the file initially yes, both of you are right, but `sudo` or super user is needed anyway for that and for setting permissions on `/bin/chmod` as well ... I was talking about particularly the loading and running/executing part hence the special notation ... I wasn't talking about the reading part though, my bad :-).

Comment: @ilkkachu I updated the comment: I wonder: Given the mode 222 (-w--w--w-) can ld read it? And if it can, couldn't you simply copy it to elsewhere using `umask 0222; cat /bin/chmod >chmod.copy`, and finally `chmod.copy 0755 /bin/chmod; rm chmod.copy`?

Comment: @U.Windl, if you mean the command in the answer above: `sudo /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/chmod`, then yes, `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` can read it because it's being run as root via sudo, and root is exempt from the permission bits checks on reading. With `cat /bin/chmod >chmod.copy`, and given the mode 0222 (-w--w--w-), you won't be able to read it (as a regular user), since no-one has read access on it. Also, even if you do `sudo sh -c 'cat /bin/chmod >chmod.copy'`, the new file gets created without the x permission because normally programs don't add it when creating files.

Comment: @ilkkachu You are right: I was assuming all non-masked bits would be set when creating a new file.

Answer (score 25):

You did one of the most obvious things should *never* do with `chmod` - you changed `chmod` itself to not be executable. Not even the powers of `sudo` will make this command work again (in its current form - see the other answers though).

A way to get it working again would be to reinstall the GNU coreutils package with this command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall coreutils
```

A general tip (that's especially important for Linux utilities): When learning about something, *first* read up on what each command does, *secondly* try out stuff in an isolated environment (container/VM), and only *after that* should you run commands on your production system.

Comment: "and only *after* that should you run commands on your production system." One thousand upvotes!

Answer (score 15):

In addition to all the other answers, if you have `busybox` installed, you can use that by running:

```
sudo busybox chmod 0755 /usr/bin/chmod
```

Busybox can be installed by [enabling the `universe` repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository), and then running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install busybox
```

Comment: probably better to use `chmod 0755` to restore the permissions to what they originally were, instead of just adding the execute permission and leaving the other permissions off

Comment: @raj, I did wonder. Part of the reason I suggested in a comment was that I seem to have it on every Ubuntu I have access to, even ones where I don't think anyone would have explicitly installed it. The package descriptions say `busybox-static` is `Priority: standard`, which I guess it means it should be installed by default but perhaps someone will correct me.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, indeed `busybox` is being shipped by default with Ubuntu for quiet a while now.

Comment: @ilkkachu `busybox` has been included in most Linux distros to make initramfs generation easy.

Comment: @ilkkachu Indeed, it is. I assumed it's not because why anybody would need it by default on a general purpose, non space-limited system? But I have checked on my system (where I definitely did NOT install it) and it is there.

Answer (score 14):

With on-the-fly `tar` mode changing (the `#` symbol means that the command should be run as root):

```
# cd /bin
# tar -mode 755 -cf chmod.tar chmod
# tar -xf chmod.tar
```

---

Old answer calling `hexedit`:

```
# cd /bin
# tar -cf chmod.tar chmod
# hexedit chmod.tar
```

Fix the permissions inside the tarball; it's the `0000222`; change it to `0000755`. Then run:

```
# tar -xf chmod.tar
```

Comment: Doesn't mode 222 prevent reading the file?

Comment: @U.Windl: root don't care. (Intentional misspelling because meme)

Comment: Ubuntu's GNU `tar` supports changing permissions on-the-fly i.e. `sudo tar --mode 0755 -cf chmod.tar /bin/chmod`.

Answer (score 6):

According to the Emacs documentation elisp function

> set-file-modes is an interactive built-in function in `C source code'.

so most likely it uses the `chmod`o system call.

So it seems logical to assume that in "Emacs dired" `dired-do-chmod` (<kbd>M</kbd>) will use that function too, allowing to reset the file mode by opening the `/bin` directory (via "C-x C-f"), locating `chmod`, and then pressing <kbd>M</kbd> to change the mode of the selected file(s).

As help explains:

```text
M runs the command dired-do-chmod, which is an interactive autoloaded Lisp
function.

It is bound to M, <menu-bar> <operate> <chmod>.

(dired-do-chmod &optional ARG)

Change the mode of the marked (or next ARG) files.
Symbolic modes like `g+w' are allowed.
Type M-n to pull the file attributes of the file at point
into the minibuffer.
```

Answer (score 5):

As any binary allowing to use the `chmod(2)` syscall with specific mode and file can fix the problem (as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/1483466/955948), you can add your own binary when no such binary is available (assuming a working C compiler (here: gcc) is installed):

Use this specific C program:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if (chmod("/bin/chmod", 0755) != 0) {
                perror("chmod failed");
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Then compile it, and finally execute it:

```bash
% make CFLAGS="-Wall -O" chmod
% ./chmod
```

(The `make` command will execute `cc -Wall -O chmod.c -o chmod`)

Comment: C compiler and other build tools are not installed in Ubuntu by default; you need to install them first.
It's better to use some programming language that is already available with the default installation, like Perl or Python.

Comment: The OP did not make a statement whether it was a "default" installation. Of course `perl -e "chmod 0755, '/bin/chmod'"` would work, too. But one could also compile the needed binary on another machine. The binary, specifically when stripped, is probably less than 8kB in size.

Comment: if you can copy it from another system, with the copy getting the x permission bit (and being compatible wrt. any dynamic libraries), then you could likely just copy `/bin/chmod` from that other system and not need to compile anything. `scp -p /bin/chmod target:` or so.

Comment: @ilkkachu A compatible executable copy of the binary should be available through APT download ... i.e. `mkdir extracted && apt download coreutils && dpkg-deb -xv coreutils*.deb extracted` for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute a file that lacks execute permission simply by calling its interpreter. Here's a very simple example:

```
$ touch file
$ stat -c '%a' file
664
$ echo 'echo hello' > file
$ ./file
bash: ./file: Permission denied
$ bash file
hello
```

This works for `chmod` too.

```
$ file /bin/chmod
/bin/chmod: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=f73df9524f4a995d851e6f87d7934869a767f253, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

So the interpreter to call is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Let's try it.

```
$ sudo chmod 222 /bin/chmod
$ stat -c '%a' /bin/chmod
222
$ sudo /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /bin/chmod 0755 /bin/chmod
$ stat -c '%a' /bin/chmod
755
```

Answer (score 2):

**Go Go Go**

As has been written many times above, there are MANY ways to solve this issue. I want to introduce a tool using Go.

`chmodan.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fileName := "/usr/bin/chmod"

    // Magic here
    err := os.Chmod(fileName, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error os chmod work:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("File permissions have been successfully changed.")
}
```

Using:

```
> chmod --version
chmod (GNU coreutils) 8.32
> which chmod
/usr/bin/chmod
> sudo chmod 222 /usr/bin/chmod
[sudo] password for XXXXXXX: 
> chmod --version
bash: /usr/bin/chmod: Permission denied
> sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/chmod
sudo: chmod: command not found
> go build chmodan.go
> stat -c %a /usr/bin/chmod
222
> sudo ./chmodan 
File permissions have been successfully changed.
> stat -c %a /usr/bin/chmod
755
> chmod --version
chmod (GNU coreutils) 8.32
```